# Combining for-loops/while-loops and ODE45

Tags: matlab, ode

I was wondering if it's possible to combine `for-loops/while-loops and ODE45`?, please look at the example below:

I have a function (ode) which I want to solve at different `ic` (initial conditions):

```
ser = @(x) x.^(-0.3) - x.^(1.8); % the function
tspan = 1:0.02:2; 
x0 = 0.5;
% x0 = 0.8;
% x0 = 1.2; 
% x0 = 1.8;
% x0 = 2; 
% x0 = 2.5; 
[~, x_t] = ode45(@(t,x) ser(x), tspan, x0);
plot(tspan,x_t,'r-')
```

And plot the `solution curves` at the end.

Is there a way to pass the other `ic`without doing it manually, like a loop? or any other way to optimize this step? If I could receive some help with this, it will be very appreciated because I have to compute many `ODEs` (more complex ones) at 15 to 25 different `ic`.

Thanks in advance!

PS. If the code has to change (e.g. different names for the `x0`s or solutions `x_t`) it will be OK!

Comment: Am i right, that you want to plot a family of functions f_x(t). Where your family parameter x is given in an array? If so you could transfer your data to a matrix.

Comment: Hi @Minion, the plotting part is the less important actually. Can you say a little more about how this _transfer_ of _values_ to a matrix can be done? or how it will look out?

Comment: I was thinking about a matrix which with your given example code would have 6 rows with 51 columns. Each row representing one of your x0 values given above and the columns representing tspan. Then you could just plot(tspan,Matrix)

Comment: I am sorry for being so slow, but I understand that the `x0s` can make a vector `X0` which is (6x1) and I see the other `vector` (lets say `T`) made of the `tspan`, which will be `T=(1x51)` but how do you form a `matrix` of these two vectors and how can this help me to solve my problem? And, if I present to `matlab` a vector containing `n` initial conditions (this time 6), will not `matlab` think that I am passing a system of ODEs and not just a single one?

Comment: i posted a loop which should do the trick. In this loop i compute the `test_ode_45`-function i programmed for `x(i)` and all `tspan` elements saving the result in the i-th row of my test_mat. At the end you can plot it with `plot(tspan,test_mat)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a predefined no. of `ic` you can use this for loop:

```
 for i=1:NoOfic
      test_mat(i,:)=test_ode_45(x(i),tspan);
  end
```

You should predefine your matrix (test_mat) in a sufficient dimension e.g.

```
test_mat = zeros(NoOfic, SizeOftspan)
```

Obviously I have defined the variables `NoOfic`and `SizeOftspan`to the specific numbers

My whole test-code is:

```
tspan = 1:0.02:2;
x= [0.4 0.8 1.2 1.5 2.6];
sizeOftspan = size(tspan);
sizeOfFamily= size(x);
test_mat = zeros(sizeOfFamily(2),sizeOftspan(2));

test_tes= test_ode_45(x(1),tspan);
  for i=1:sizeOfFamily(2)
      test_mat(i,:)=test_ode_45(x(i),tspan);
  end
plot(tspan, test_mat)
```

Where my `test_ode_45` function is a simple x*sin(t) function

Comment: Sweet! Thanks @Minion for the visual example, I understand now! And, each `row` from `test_mat` corresponds to a `time-series`/`solution` right? or will it be each `column`?

Comment: it depends on your implementation. if you do it like i did each row represents a time series (51 elements). But you can change the code easily to transpose it. Just remember to change the definition of `test_mat` as well as the position of the loop index in the matrix

Comment: @Minion I believe I am doing something wrong but I can not see where the error is. I have used you code, just modified a bit including a`handle function` and I notices something on the plot, instead of having the curves started at the `ic` I have them starting at different values... Please look the extended version of my question above.

Comment: @SergioHaram If you are wondering why the graph doesn't start at [1 2 3] respectevily its just because of your `sin(t)<=1`. If you want a `sin`which is shifted by x. Try `x+sin(t)`as test function. If your problem is sth. else pls explain it more thoroughly. Also when you change your `tspan` to `tspan=0:0.02:7`you see that the outcome is a family of sine-functions

Comment: @Minion yes, that was my concern, the initial values of the graphs. It was a strange _behavior_ of the graphs, but now that you have clarify this to me I have no more questions. Thanks once again!